# What is class=“md-2n” in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

What is this 'md' stands for? I know 'm' stands for margin, but what about 'd' : the first line of code?

And this 'n2' - what's this 'n' stands for?  Is it different from a single '2' like: the second line of code

```
<a class="navbar-brand  mr-md-n2">
<a class="navbar-brand mr-md-2">
```

Comment: `margin-right: 0.5rem` md is `breakpoint` Its use to target specific viewports - Read more here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/utilities-for-layout/

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/

Comment: the `md` means `medium`

Comment: `mr` means Margin Right, and `md` is Medium Screen in bootstrap

Comment: thank you for who answer me ,, i see what md is , but I don't know what's meaning of this'n2', what this 'n' stands for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'n' in 'n2' stands for negative. So in your case `mr-md-n2` is `margin-right on medium breakpoint: - 0.5 rem`

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow.

From [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/):

```
{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}
```

So this `mr-md-2` means "{margin}{right}-{medium}-{2}"

Comment: thank you for your response , i see what md is , but I don't know what's meaning of this'n2', what this 'n' stands for